# javascript clickable text

Tags: javascript, html

this should be a pretty basic question.
I would like to have some html listing:

- A
- B
- C

And by clicking on one of the elements, something should be displayed below. For example, when clicking B, we obtain:

- A
- B 
  "bla bla bla"
- C

I guess there are many ways to achieve that. I just would like the easiest/cleanest way to do that.

Thanks, 
Arnaud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
function open_item(sender) {
    sender.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

...

<ul>
   <li onclick="open_item(this);">
      A
      <div style="display: none;">bla bla</div>
   </li>
   <li onclick="open_item(this);">
      B
      <div style="display: none;">bla bla</div>
   </li>
   <li onclick="open_item(this);">
      C
      <div style="display: none;">bla bla</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

One of many, many, many ways to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery.
Give every element an ID, set a onClick listener via jQuery to every element and let it run a function which looks for a child element (like a `<p>` or something you wanna surround your content with) and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery function that uses insertAfter

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('<span>blah blah</span>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/WwCcF/

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic content with jQuery :

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).append("<br />bla bla bla");
});
```

I write a pure JavaScript code...